# Getting values from query string in an URL using AngularJS $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Regarding `$location.search`, the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location) say,

> Return search part (as object) of current url when called without any parameter.

In my URL, my query string has a param `?test_user_bLzgB` without a value. Also `$location.search()` returns an object. How do I get the actual text?

Comment: What Object do you get? Do you have a plunkr or a fiddle that demonstrates the issue that you face? You are correct when you use `$location.search()` but I wish to check the "object" that you get when you call it...

Comment: I don't know what object it is. I tried enumerating the properties but there doesn't appear to be any.

Comment: Not sure how to do a fiddle that examines a query string.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Not sure if it has changed since the accepted answer was accepted, but it is possible.

`$location.search()` will return an object of key-value pairs, the same pairs as the query string. A key that has no value is just stored in the object as true. In this case, the object would be:

```
{"test_user_bLzgB": true}
```

You could access this value directly with `$location.search().test_user_bLzgB`

Example (with larger query string): http://fiddle.jshell.net/TheSharpieOne/yHv2p/4/show/?test_user_bLzgB&somethingElse&also&something=Somethingelse

Note: Due to hashes (as it will go to http://fiddle.jshell.net/#/url, which would create a new fiddle), this fiddle will not work in browsers that do not support js history (will not work in IE <10)

Edit:
As pointed out in the comments by @Naresh and @DavidTchepak, the `$locationProvider` also needs to be configured properly: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/guide/$location#-location-service-configuration

Comment: As Naresh mentioned, `$locationProvider` also needs to be configured properly: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/guide/$location#-location-service-configuration (This tripped me up. Hopefully the link saves others some time.)

Comment: To configure location provider, you need:
window.app.config ['$locationProvider', ($locationProvider) ->
  $locationProvider.html5Mode true
]
You also need a base tag in the HTML file:
<base href="/">

Comment: Thanks for inspriation and useful tips, just share my case. I create a constant called userConfig and put everything inside, some settings can be overriden by query string for user flexibility. I use this and put the query in a globalController scope variable which is in HTML tag so any child controller can take the parameter including service. Because the userConfig is also put in the Service. So virtually, they can interact together.

Comment: I found it easier to just use a js function, $location.search() has to many moving parts.  There are plenty of code examples out there for getting query string parameters.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne if you have a moment could you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121888/where-to-capture-the-location-search-vars-in-the-run-statement-in-order-to-r

Answer (score 49):

If you just need to look at the query string as text, you can use: `$window.location.search`

Comment: How is this not an answer? Maybe it is a bit short, but it _does_ seem to answer the question.

Comment: If you check the timestamps, the answer was edited 2 hours after Dan's comment.  It's really not that important, but i found it shocking that leo's comment was getting upvoted so i thought i'd point it out.

Answer (score 41):

`$location.search()` returns an object, consisting of the keys as variables and the values as its value. 
So: if you write your query string like this:

```
?user=test_user_bLzgB
```

You could easily get the text like so:

```
$location.search().user
```

If you wish not to use a key, value like ?foo=bar, I suggest using a hash #test_user_bLzgB ,

and calling

```
$location.hash()
```

would return 'test_user_bLzgB' which is the data you wish to retrieve.

Additional info:

If you used the query string method and you are getting an empty object with $location.search(), 
it is probably because Angular is using the hashbang strategy instead of the html5 one... 
To get it working, add this config to your module

```
yourModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);    
}]);
```

Answer (score 13):

First make the URL format correct for getting the query string use **#?q=string** that works for me

```
http://localhost/codeschool/index.php#?foo=abcd
```

Inject $location service into the controller

```
app.controller('MyController', [ '$location', function($location) { 

    var searchObject = $location.search();

    // $location.search(); reutrn object 
    // searchObject = { foo = 'abcd' };

    alert( searchObject.foo );

} ]);
```

So the out put should be **abcd**

Answer (score 10):

you can use this as well

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var queryValue = getParameterByName('test_user_bLzgB');
```

Comment: You've copied that function from another SOF answer... best to reference your source.

Comment: Yep this is what I use, got it from somewhere on SO

Answer (score 10):

If your `$location.search()` is not working, then make sure you have the following:

1) `html5Mode(true)` is configured in app's module config

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

2) `<base href="/">` is present in your HTML

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

References:

1. [base href="/"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31098416/1161370)
2. [html5Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19440225/1161370)

Comment: "html5Mode(true) is configured in app's module config" -- explain

Comment: @EdPlunkett - Sorry, I meant to say it's configured in the config method of an angular app object. Eg here it is:
var appModule = angular.module('myAppModule', []);

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty new to Angular

Comment: Yes, that's so important, faced the same issue

Answer (score 7):

Angular does not support this kind of query string.

The query part of the URL is supposed to be a `&`-separated sequence of key-value pairs, thus perfectly interpretable as an object.

There is no API at all to manage query strings that do not represent sets of key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

In my NodeJS example, I have an url "localhost:8080/Lists/list1.html?x1=y" that I want to traverse and acquire values.

In order to work with $location.search() to get x1=y, I have done a few things

1. script source to angular-route.js
2. Inject 'ngRoute' into your app module's dependencies
3. Config your locationProvider
4. Add the base tag for $location (if you don't, your search().x1 would return nothing or undefined. Or if the base tag has the wrong info, your browser would not be able to find your files inside script src that your .html needs. Always open page's view source to test your file locations!)
5. invoke the location service (search())

my list1.js has

```
    var app = angular.module('NGApp', ['ngRoute']);  //dependencies : ngRoute
    app.config(function ($locationProvider) { //config your locationProvider
         $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('');
    });

    app.controller('NGCtrl', function ($scope, datasvc, $location) {// inject your location service
        //var val = window.location.href.toString().split('=')[1];
        var val = $location.search().x1;    alert(val);
        $scope.xout = function () {
           datasvc.out(val)
           .then(function (data) {
              $scope.x1 = val;
              $scope.allMyStuffs = data.all;
           });
        };
        $scope.xout();
    });
```

and my list1.html has

```
<head>
    <base href=".">
    </head>
<body ng-controller="NGCtrl">
<div>A<input ng-model="x1"/><br/><textarea ng-model="allMyStuffs"/></div>
<script src="../js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="list1.js"></script>
</body>
```

Guide: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/guide/$location

Answer (score 0):

My fix is more simple, create a factory, and implement as one variable. For example

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

// This a searchCustom factory. Copy the factory and implement in the controller
.factory("searchCustom", function($http,$log){    
    return {
        valuesParams : function(params){
            paramsResult = [];
            params = params.replace('(', '').replace(')','').split("&");
            
            for(x in params){
                paramsKeyTmp = params[x].split("=");
                
                // Si el parametro esta disponible anexamos al vector paramResult
                if (paramsKeyTmp[1] !== '' && paramsKeyTmp[1] !== ' ' && 
                    paramsKeyTmp[1] !== null){          
                    
                    paramsResult.push(params[x]);
                }
            }
            
            return paramsResult;
        }
    }
})

.controller("SearchController", function($scope, $http,$routeParams,$log,searchCustom){
    $ctrl = this;
    
    var valueParams = searchCustom.valuesParams($routeParams.value);
    valueParams = valueParams.join('&');

    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url: webservice+"q?"+valueParams
    }).then( function successCallback(response){
        data = response.data;
        $scope.cantEncontrados = data.length; 
        $scope.dataSearch = data;
        
    } , function errorCallback(response){
        console.log(response.statusText);
    })
      
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="SearchController">
<form action="#" >
                          
                            
                            <input ng-model="param1" 
                                   placeholder="param1" />
                            
                            <input  ng-model="param2" 
                                    placeholder="param2"/>
                        
<!-- Implement in the html code 
(param1={{param1}}&param2={{param2}}) -> this is a one variable, the factory searchCustom split and restructure in the array params
-->          
                        <a href="#seach/(param1={{param1}}&param2={{param2}})">
                            <buttom ng-click="searchData()" >Busqueda</buttom>
                        </a>
                    </form> 
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer :( but for someone who is in need,
this works Angular js works too :) **URLSearchParams** Let's have a look at how we can use this new API to get values from the location!

> // Assuming "?post=1234&action=edit"

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
console.log(urlParams.has('post')); // true
console.log(urlParams.get('action')); // "edit"
console.log(urlParams.getAll('action')); // ["edit"]
console.log(urlParams.toString()); // "?post=1234&action=edit"
console.log(urlParams.append('active', '1')); // "?

post=1234&action=edit&active=1"
```

## **FYI: IE is not supported**

use this function from instead of **URLSearchParams**

```
urlParam = function (name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)')
                      .exec(window.location.search);

    return (results !== null) ? results[1] || 0 : false;
}

console.log(urlParam('action')); //edit
```