# Make AngularJS page double as search results page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, filter, pageload

I have a basic table in which I'm displaying data, as pulled from a database, through AngularJS. I also have a search field that uses AngularJS to filter the data:

```
<input ng-model="search" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" value="">
<div ng-controller="eventsController")>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="event in events | filter:search">
            <td><span ng-bind="event.title"></span></td>
            <td><span ng-bind="event.date_start"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    function EventsController($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/api/all-events').success(function(events) {
            $scope.events = events;
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is great for user-defined searches, but what if I want to run a particular filter upon page load while maintaining the search functionality? Is there a way that I can use AngularJS to automatically filter the results based on a URL parameter (i.e. example.com?search=foo)? Ideally, the value of the the input field would also be set to the URL parameter.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with filtering. All you're asking about is how to get the `$routeParams` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) or querystring (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964444/get-query-string-using-angularjs). Once you check for `search`, just set the `$scope.search` as that value and everything should fall into place

Comment: I think you need to add `$location` to your controller.  `EventsController($scope, $http, $location)`  The $location service parses the URL in the browser address bar.  Then use `$location.search()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments said, this has nothing to do with `filter`. It's more about how you organize your code to customize URL path you send to the server. You can try to do it this way:

```
function EventsController($scope, $http) {
    // this field is bound to ng-model="search" in your HTML 
    $scope.search = 'ALL';

    $scope.fetchResults = function() {
        var path;
        if ($scope.search === 'ALL') {
            path = '/api/all-events';
        } else {
            path = '/search?input=' + $scope.search;
        }

        // here we send different URL path
        // depending on the condition of $scope.search
        $http.get(path).success(function(events) {
            $scope.events = events;
        });
    };

    // this line will be called once when controller is initialized
    $scope.fetchResults();
}
```

And your HTML code, make sure your controller is on the parent div of the input field and search button. And for the search button, you invoke `fetchResults()` when it's clicked:

```
<div ng-controller="eventsController")>
    <input ng-model="search" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" value="">
    <button ng-click="fetchResults()">Search</button>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="event in events | filter:search">
                <td><span ng-bind="event.title"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="event.date_start"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```