# Angular error running Karma tests: HTML5 mode requires a <base> tag

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I have a single-page Angular app with a Rails backend. I am using a  tag in my `index.html` file, but when I run my front-end unit tests using Karma, I get this:

```
$location in HTML5 mode requires a <base> tag to be present
```

I am doing this in my main .js file:

```
angular.module('my.module').config( function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode( true );
}
```

So, is there any way I can inject a `<base>` element in the page that karma actually renders? Or else, tell Angular/Karma to ignore this error when running unit tests?

### Update

[This Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/o2sKYnuqkb0) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8866) both describe this problem but in both cases the solution is to simply bump up the version of Angular. I've done that and I can even see the line in `angular-mocks.js` where the default `baseHref` gets set...

Here is the spec in question:

```
describe 'amnResource', ->
  $compile = null
  $rootScope = null

  beforeEach ->
    module 'ngMock'
    module 'amn'
    module 'directive.template.cache'

    inject([ '$compile', '$rootScope', ($c, $r) ->
      $compile = $c
      $rootScope = $r
    ])

  it 'compiles to an article', ->
    console.log $rootScope
    console.log $rootScope.foo
    $rootScope.foo =
      title: 'Foo'
      excerpt: 'foo bar qux'

    element = $compile('<amn-resource resource="foo"></amn-resource>')($rootScope)
    console.log element.html()
    console.log $rootScope.foo
    expect( element.html() ).toMatch /Foo/
```

Karma output:

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.28 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.9.5)]: Connected on socket hOvsC6ji15heHZmiHxJt with id 45528987
ERROR: 'Error: [$location:nobase] $location in HTML5 mode requires a <base> tag to be present!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$location/nobase
    at http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:63:12
    at $LocationProvider.$get (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:11187:15)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:4138:17)
    at $LocationProvider.origProvider.$get (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:4024:43)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:4138:17)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:3956:37
    at getService (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:4097:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:4129:13)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:3956:37
    at getService (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:4097:39)'
ERROR: 'Error: [$location:nobase] $location in HTML5 mode requires a <base> tag to be present!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$location/nobase
    at http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:63:12
    at $LocationProvider.$get (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:11187:15)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:4138:17)
    at $LocationProvider.origProvider.$get (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:4024:43)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:4138:17)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:3956:37
    at getService (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:4097:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:4129:13)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:3956:37
    at getService (http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js?3a16995fbea0062d6334adb9277e9776ca069fa1:4097:39)'
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.9.5) Midway: Resource performs a GET request FAILED
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
LOG: Scope{$id: 2, $$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: null, $parent: null, $$phase: null, $root: Scope{$id: 2, $$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: null, $parent: null, $$phase: null, $root: Scope{$id: ..., $$childTail: ..., $$childHead: ..., $$prevSibling: ..., $$nextSibling: ..., $$watchers: ..., $parent: ..., $$phase: ..., $root: ..., $$destroyed: ..., $$listeners: ..., $$listenerCount: ..., $$isolateBindings: ..., $$asyncQueue: ..., $$postDigestQueue: ..., $$applyAsyncQueue: ...}, $$destroyed: false, $$listeners: Object{}, $$listenerCount: Object{}, $$isolateBindings: null, $$asyncQueue: [], $$postDigestQueue: [], $$applyAsyncQueue: []}, $$destroyed: false, $$listeners: Object{}, $$listenerCount: Object{}, $$isolateBindings: null, $$asyncQueue: [], $$postDigestQueue: [], $$applyAsyncQueue: []}
LOG: undefined
LOG: ''
LOG: Object{title: 'Foo', excerpt: 'foo bar qux'}
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.9.5) amnResource compiles to an article FAILED
    Expected '' to match /Foo/.
    Error: Expected '' to match /Foo/.
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/acobster/Dropbox/amn/amn-0.5/spec/javascripts/unit/directives/resource_spec.js:27:35)
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.9.5): Executed 3 of 3 (2 FAILED) (5.078 secs / 5.074 secs)
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can disable the base tag check by doing the following:

```js
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

Comment: cool solution I've used it in my production and it's works nicelly

Comment: That solves the problem but breaks functionality of nested states

Comment: @FarzadYZ if you actually have a base other than `/` then this would break your application, yes.  Otherwise, it shouldn't affect nested states.

Comment: This didn't work for me for the reasons stated above I didn't have a / as the base.  I eventually just started manually parsing it out from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534612/angularjs-get-query-string-values-without-a-hash-in-the-link

Comment: I found if I add ngMock as a module dependency, then it goes away: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock. The problem is I don't want to have that dependency in product mode. Still figuring it out...

Answer (score 22):

You can specify your base tag in your index.html `<head>` like that:

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

Source: [from angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase)

Comment: Thanks @Jerry, I do know how to write a `<base>` tag in HTML, and I have one in my actual application markup. ;-) I tried to convey in my question that Karma is actually generating a different, more minimal index.html file (presumable so as to isolate the code for testing) and that's where I need to "inject" one. The answer above provided one solution (tell Angular to ignore its absence) but if you know of a way to tell Karma/Angular to generate an index.html _with a base tag_, that'd be preferred. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you can't or do not want to set `requireBase` to `false`, the solution - as others pointed out - is to add `<base href="/">` in the header of your primary HTML file. To do this, you will need to specify custom HTML files for Karma, which you can then edit.

First find and copy `node_modules/karma/static/context.html` and `node_modules/karma/static/debug.html` to your unit test folder, and amend the headers of both.

Then in your karma.conf.js add the following two lines:

```
customContextFile: 'test/unit/context.html',
customDebugFile:   'test/unit/debug.html',
```

Of course your path may vary.

Comment: Worked like a charm, the other comments didn't specify how to use the base href with Karma config