# AngularJS: Get query string values without a hash in the link

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to get query string values using angularjs.

my Url: `http://localhost/example.php?sportsId=3`

when I applied `var goto = $location.search()['sportsId'];`
it returns me undefined.

However, if I add hash in url like `Url: http://localhost/example.php#?sportsId=3`

then it returns me correct value 3.

But in this case, it also gives me `Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$parse/syntax?p0=undefined&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=null&p3=sportsID%3D&p4=sportsID%3D`

Also, my default `$_REQUEST['sportsId']` is not working with hash format.

How can I correctly get values from query string by using angularjs?

Comment: I think following question can help you in your issue.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063673/whats-the-most-concise-way-to-read-query-parameters-in-angularjs][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063673/whats-the-most-concise-way-to-read-query-parameters-in-angularjs

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I know this is not Angular but its pure JS and works like a charm (just don't add dummyPath and it will take the URL).

```
function getUrlParameter(param, dummyPath) {
        var sPageURL = dummyPath || window.location.search.substring(1),
            sURLVariables = sPageURL.split(/[&||?]/),
            res;

        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i += 1) {
            var paramName = sURLVariables[i],
                sParameterName = (paramName || '').split('=');

            if (sParameterName[0] === param) {
                res = sParameterName[1];
            }
        }

        return res;
}
```

Usage:

```
var sportdsId = getUrlParameter('sportsId');
```

Comment: Nice. Just need to decode the string: res = decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));

Answer (score 3):

Three simple steps did the Job:

1. Config angular for HTML5 mode by adding the following code to your controller/service:

   app.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
2. Add base element to your HTML:

```html
<base href="/">
```

3. Inject "$location" into your angular controller:

   app.controller('ABCController', ['$scope', '$location', ABCController]);

Finally to get the query string use the following code:

```
var yourId = $location.search().yourId;
```

The answer is already there in previous answers, I just summarized for better understanding. Hopefully somebody will become beneficial from it.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer below links

```
var goto = $location.search().sportsId;
```

[Getting values from query string in an url using AngularJS $location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964444/get-query-string-using-angularjs)

Comment: var goto = $location.search().sportsId; doesn't work. returns me undefined

Comment: This answer requires you to adjust your $locationProvider as well which may not work in all instances.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use. It's essentially the same as the accepted answer but returns all parameters as an object and handle decoding of url components.

```
function getUrlParameters() {
    var pairs = window.location.search.substring(1).split(/[&?]/);
    var res = {}, i, pair;
    for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        pair = pairs[i].split('=');
        if (pair[1])
            res[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
$location.search()
```

This returns an object with your params so lets say you have
url?param1=val&param2=val2

This will give the following back

```
{ param1 : val, param2 : val2 }
```

Also make sure you enable

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your self a search object from the the `$window.location.search` property using the following:

```
    var search = $window.location.search
            .split(/[&||?]/)
            .filter(function (x) { return x.indexOf("=") > -1; })
            .map(function (x) { return x.split(/=/); })
            .map(function (x) {
                x[1] = x[1].replace(/\+/g, " ");
                return x;
            })
            .reduce(function (acc, current) {
                acc[current[0]] = current[1];
                return acc;
            }, {});

    var sportsId = search.sportsId;
```

or create a `queryString` factory which you can use anywhere.. This combines the left and right parts of the queryString.. I.e. before `#` and after the `#`

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("myModuleName")
        .factory("queryString", QueryStringFactory);

    function QueryStringFactory($window, $location) {

        function search() {

            var left = $window.location.search
                .split(/[&||?]/)
                .filter(function (x) { return x.indexOf("=") > -1; })
                .map(function (x) { return x.split(/=/); })
                .map(function (x) {
                    x[1] = x[1].replace(/\+/g, " ");
                    return x;
                })
                .reduce(function (acc, current) {
                    acc[current[0]] = current[1];
                    return acc;
                }, {});

            var right = $location.search() || {};

            var leftAndRight = Object.keys(right)
                .reduce(function(acc, current) {
                    acc[current] = right[current];
                    return acc;
                }, left);

            return leftAndRight;
        }

        return {
            search: search
        };

    }

}());
```

usage:

```
var qs = queryString.search();
var sportsId = sq.sportsId;
```

Comment: I don't know, but it looks too much code for a simple op.