# How do you parse URL value in angularJS for global site search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

A URL parameter has two parts. A variable name and a value. In example below, "coupon" is the variable name and "50_2013" is the value:

http://unbouncepages.com/puravida?coupon=50_2013

Let's say I want to pre-fill a coupon code on my form.

Using the example above, you'd just need to add a "coupon" field to your form and it would automatically pre-fill with the matching query parameter.
But I don't know how to do this in AngularJS as I'm a newbie.

Like this:

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBOa8.jpg)

I would like to achieve the above result with "Page reload navigation" For example, when reloading the page passed value in the new text box.
Should I use '$window.location.href' but how?

Comment: Are you using ui-router by any chance?

Comment: Check Below Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534612/angularjs-get-query-string-values-without-a-hash-in-the-link

Comment: How do I call this method in search form? Does't know how to do that.

Comment: Not using ui-router ... I'll look into this.