# Navigating to url directly after removing hashbangs not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am using angular for my app

I wanted to remove the # from the url so i added the below lines as suggested in [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28686169/848841)

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

In the index.html I also added the below code as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28686169/848841)

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
</head>
```

It all works fine when I navigate to pages from the home, but when i copy the url and open it in new tab, it throws `404 error`

**Example**

When I launch the app, it's opening `http://localhost:portno/home`.
When I refresh the page, I'm getting a 404 error.

What other configuration should i make?

My code structure is as below

```
  .state('tab.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'tab-home': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
                    controller: 'templeHome'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('tab.list', {
            url: '/list',
            views: {
                'tab-home': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
                    controller: 'templeList'
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: i had to try this . But i can't get clear solutions for it. how to overcome this issues

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `route` on your server that will redirect you to the entrypoint of your front (i.e: `index.html`).

For example, if you were redirected from your home to `http://localhost:portno/foo/bar`, you'll need a `route` to match the `/foo/bar` one that will redirect you to your `index.html`.

It migth look like this (note that this is an **example code of my own written for Hapi**):

```
server.route([
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/foo/bar',
        handler: function(request, reply) {
            reply.file('./public/index.html');
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: should i add this in app.js ?

Comment: You should add it to your server

Comment: basically i should redirect all direct page requests to the home page of the site so that state will be maintained from there on?

Comment: Yes, all the Angular pages have to be redirected to the `index.html`. The Angular app will take care of the route itself and display the right page :)

Comment: so if i request for `/product/beat-headphones/someproductid` and redirect it to `./public/index.html` will it redirect to the product page?

Comment: Assuming that `./public/index.html` is your Angular app entrypoint, it should yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87264/discussion-between-vignesh-and-erazihel).