# MVC with angular Node.js and mongodb

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, node.js, oauth

I am building a e-commerce application using MVC with angular and Node.js

The architecture diagram is as below

[image]

In MVC, I am using partial views which will contain sections like "**Featured products**", "**Favourite products**" etc. These will be used in pages where ever required by using `@Html.partial("layoutname")`. Also header/footer etc are in the shared folder as layouts

The authentication is handled using  `oAuth`, which will provide the token to the user. Request for data are sent to Node.js and it will validate the token again `for requests which requires user details` like fetching favourites etc

I am doing this by configuring the app.js in node.js

```
if (req.method == "POST") {
        try {
            AuthenticationFunction();
           //this will authenticate the token and call next() if success
        }
        catch (ex) {
            res.send("Some message");
        }
    }
```

For data binding I use Angular

Are there any better alternates that should be used in this architecture?

- I use MVC for its ability to route requests, will normal iframe and 
     plain html be faster than cshtml pages?     (I tried angular routing but was [not able to remove the # from url and get it working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981730/navigating-to-url-directly-after-removing-hashbangs-not-working))
- In node.js should I use passport.js? will it be faster/better than
     my current approach?
- Is this model secure? I send the token and userid with request and validate them in node.js for requests requiring this authentication

Comment: Why exactly do you need Node.js middleware? From what you describe you can completely remove it. If access to it not IP restricted/protected by firewall (so only your MVC will be able to use it) there is absolutely no gain in it. It only adds 2 unnecessary web requests to your data flow...

Comment: I think i have missed some detail.

I am using node.js to fetch the data from mongodb
Previously i was using service stack for fetching data

Comment: Why can't you fetch data from Mongo using asp.net?

Comment: Then you really shouldn't use it!!. You can easily work with MongoDb with something like https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoRepository/ . If you are using multi layer architecture then just use this repository as data access layer. As I said it is absolutely redundant to run Node.js server for accessing MongoDb

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Yes I also tried C# drivers
But looks like node.js is faster than C# drivers, web apis and Service stack

Comment: @AlexArt. I read somewhere that NIO servers(Node js) will be faster than BIO servers(IIS), 
I use ajax calls to fetch data in presentation layer(MVC+angular)

Comment: You are making 2 unnecessary web requests :-). Instead of 1 "SLOW" call to MongoDb from MVC you are making a "SLOW" call to Node.js server from MVC(IIS) which is going to make a "FAST" call to MongoDb and then going return a result to the "SLOW"  MVC(IIS). Does it really look like it is going to be faster?

Comment: If you think that IIS is not fast enough for you (The assumption that I really doubt - StackExchange servers are IIS - and I would say that stackoverflow is not slow at all) you should not use IIS at all

Comment: @AlexArt. Nice comment :)  yeah it doesn't 
I was previously using plain html pages routed with angular and hosted it in azure. The pages were very fast
Now after moving to mvc, initial page load is slower!!
Also i hosted c# driver and Node js on azure and tested the load time in https://www.dotcom-tools.com/website-speed-test.aspx, node.js was having  10-30% lesser load time than servicestack

Comment: @AlexArt. thanks for your inputs :) 
I am not able to understand reduced network call
For example in my scenario i am loading 5 data initially and on every scroll i am loading 5 more data
Currently when user hits end of page Ui->function call to node js -> Call to Mongo -> gets data
the same will be applicable if i use C# driver 
user hits end of page->some server side c# code -> call to mongodb -> gets data