# angularjs SEO friendly url does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, routes, seo

I want to make my expressjs + angularjs SEO friendly and I read a lots of articles about $locationProvider. I`m using this code but my app does not run and show a blank page in the browser:

**It`s my angular code:**

```
var myApp = angular.module("PlannerApp" , ['ngRoute' , 'appControllers' , 'ngAnimate']);
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers' , []);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider' , '$locationProvider' , function($routeProvider , $routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
when("/home" , 
     {templateUrl : "../home.html",
      controller: 'HomepageCtrl'
    }).
when("/about" ,
    {templateUrl : "../about.html",
      controller: 'AboutpageCtrl'
    }).
otherwise({templateUrl : "../home.html"});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

}]);

function HomepageCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.$parent.seo = {
    pageTitle : 'home',
    pageDescripton: 'home We are a content heavy website so we need to be indexed.'
  };
}

function AboutpageCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.$parent.seo = {
    pageTitle : 'aboute ',
    pageDescripton: 'aboute We are a content heavy website so we need to be indexed.'
  };
}

myApp.run(function(){
   console.log("runde");
});
```

**This is the output:**

[image]

Comment: problem was here too: myApp.config(['$routeProvider' , '$locationProvider' , function($routeProvider , $routeProvider){

Comment: adding  $routeProvider to function variables

Answer (score 0):

You may have to insert a base tag in your html file:

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31098416/1005137

Comment: woooow It solved by add <base href="/"> and another edit that I edit my question as well.

Comment: Tanks it worded but there is another problem. when I change the route, It works currently but when enter the address of my site directly in browser, it shoe me error : Cannot GET /about   :(

Comment: I prefer this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router opposed to the default Angular router. You may want to check it as well :)

Comment: second problem was solved too by managing request in expressjs: app.get("/about" , function(req , resp , next){
 resp.sendFile(__dirname + "/statics/theme.html");
});

Comment: If your problem is Express, then you may want to use:
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/statics/));`

You may find more information here:
[Express static routing](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)