# how to solve error "[$location:nobase] $location in HTML5 mode requires a <base> tag to be present!"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have no idea how to solve this case.

> Error: [$location:nobase] $location in HTML5 mode requires a 
>   tag to be present! http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$location/nobase
>   at angular.js:68 at $LocationProvider.$get (angular.js:13384) at
>   Object.invoke (angular.js:4709) at angular.js:4508 at getService
>   (angular.js:4655)
>       at injectionArgs (angular.js:4679)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4701)
>       at angular.js:4508
>       at getService (angular.js:4655)
>       at injectionArgs (angular.js:4679)

Comment: Add a base tag?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#relative-links

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular error running Karma tests: HTML5 mode requires a <base> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307914/angular-error-running-karma-tests-html5-mode-requires-a-base-tag)

Answer (score 13):

This happens when you have set `html5mode`, like so :

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
 enabled: true,
 requireBase: false
});
```

Just add a tag in your HTML template like so :

```
<head>
 <base href="/">
 ...
</head>
```

It's exactly same thing mentioned in the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase