# ng-repeat add style on querystring

Tags: angularjs, url, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to add class active on a list of li elements being generated by AngularJS if the current li key field is equal to the ID parameter in the querystring.  Something like this kind of behavior:

```
foreach person in people
{
      if person.id = urlparameter.id
       {
               writeline <li id=person.id class="active">person.name<li/>
       }
       else
       {
       writeline <li id=person.id class="">person.name<li/>
       }
}
```

The first issue is how to return the value of the query string parameter and then secondly how to use add that in the ng-repeat to add the class conditionally.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964444/get-query-string-using-angularjs) shows how to get the url parameters

Then if you have $scope.people and $scope.idFromUrl defined in your controller this html should do what you want

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people", ng-class="{'active':person.id==idFromUrl}" >
{{person.name}}
</li>
```

Comment: second part works. Cannot get url parameter to work.. injecting the $locationprovider causes previously working output to not display filterApp.config(['$locationProvider' ,function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
        
    }]);

Comment: @rdurant what does $location.search() return? is your url correct?

Comment: you need to inject $location

Comment: http://localhost:49526/Policies/Edit?CID=242&POLID=317... I am injecting $location into the controller var filterApp = angular.module('filterApp', []);

    filterApp.controller('filterAppCtrl', function ($scope,$location) {

Comment: is that what $location.search returns?

Comment: blank or null.  when I do this $scope.urllocation = $location.search(); and then try to print out {{urllocation}} it prints out {}.. not sure why

Comment: hard to tell from here, try some of the other $location getters, maybe your url is not correctly formed ?

Comment: $location.search is returning an object Edit?POLID=625&CID=466:113 Object {}.. figured it out by writing to console.. need the value of POLID