# How to find exact querystring value in angular js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, angularjs

How to find exact querystring parameter value in angularjs

```
Querystring is-->http://localhost/Emp/EmpInfoPage.aspx?empId=104569&empAccessId=100,101,102&empLoc=IND
```

So,I need to find out exact empAccessId=100,101,102 which has comma too.
Thanks is Advance

Comment: Use `$location.search().empAccessId` in your controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get query string using Angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964444/get-query-string-using-angularjs)

Comment: may be help you http://www.angulartutorial.net/2015/04/get-url-parameter-using-angular-js.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this npm package called [Query String Manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qsm)
That package has a two relevant methods for your.

first method is called `get()` which works like this

```
var accessId = qsm.get(window.location.href, 'empAccessId');
// accessId === 100,101,102
```

the second method is called `objectify()` and this returns the correct datatype for the querystring aswell, which means a comma separated string converts into an array like this

```
var queryObj = qsm.objectify('http://localhost/Emp/EmpInfoPage.aspx?empId=104569&empAccessId=100,101,102&empLoc=IND');

queryObj = {
  empId: 104569, // <- this is an integer/number
  empAccessId: [100, 101, 102], // <- this is an array
  empLoc: 'IND' // <- this is a regular string.
}
```