# Fetch URL data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http, redirect, payment-gateway

I need to fetch the data appended to the URL from a redirect URL. Following is my service. How do I get it?

```css
        paymentResponse.redirectPayment = function () {
            //return $http.get(urlBase);
            return $http({
                    method: 'POST', 
                    url: urlBase + redirectAPI, 
                    headers:{
                                'api_key': apiKey
                            },
                    data: { 
                             "type":"redirect",
                             "_id":"id",
                             "currency":"EUR",
                             "amount":100,
                             "description": "This is a test",
                             "result_options": {
                                "notification_url": null,
                                "redirect_url": $location.protocol() + '://'+ $location.host() +':'+  $location.port()  +'#/sucessresponse',
                                "cancel_url": $location.protocol() + '://'+ $location.host() +':'+  $location.port()  +'#/scan',
                                "close_window": true 
                            }
                         }
                    });
            };
```

So, now, on cancle, it redirects from my third party api back to - say -
"http://localhost:9000/#/scan?section_id=test_id".

Now, how do I fetch "section_id=test_id" in my angular app?

Comment: Please take a look for detailed answer on[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964444/getting-values-from-query-string-in-an-url-using-angularjs-location)

Comment: Please check this out [how to get query string parameters from url in angularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964444/getting-values-from-query-string-in-an-url-using-angularjs-location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$location.search()` will give you an object with all the query parameters.

For example with the url `http://localhost:9000/#/scan?section_id=test_id`. `$location.search()` will give you the following JS object

```
{
    'section_id': 'test_id'
}
```

See the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search) for details

Comment: Where should I do it? In my success resposne? It says Search of undefined

Comment: Thanks, it helped! But, please guid me if adding manually "#" is the right way for redirect url?

Comment: Not sure where you're trying to use it. Perhaps it should be another question.

Comment: Other question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051012/android-integration-url-redirect