# How to get the last (=) value 78?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, url-parameters, window.location

Angular js code. This is my current code, which helped to get first equal parameter. how to get the last = value ? i mean 78

```
var url = window.location.href; 
$scope.productId = url.split("=")[1];
/index.php?pageid=444082155630322#/tab/details?product_id=78
```

Comment: In AngularJS -> [__Getting values from query string in an url using AngularJS $location__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964444/getting-values-from-query-string-in-an-url-using-angularjs-location)

Comment: Are you  using Angular routing?

Comment: no. I am just getting parameter through window.location.href. Can you help on