# Where to capture the $location.search() vars in the run statement? In order to rebuild the state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

#### Goal / Expected

Rebuild the state of the app if the user directly goes to a link like this: `http://localhost:8080/app/#!/tag_id=5&ticker=GOOG`

#### Results

The app currently still redirects back to `/login` via `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');`

---

In my app I am storing the `$state` (ui-router) variables in a cookie using `ngCookies`.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    const shareUrl = () => {
        // const base = 'https://www.tickertags.com/dashboard/#/';
        const base = 'http://localhost:8080/app/#!/';
        const cookie = $cookies.get('stateCookie');
        console.log('state vars', $httpParamSerializer(JSON.parse(cookie)));
        const parsedState = $httpParamSerializer(JSON.parse(cookie));
        return `${base}${parsedState}`;
    };
    // console.log('state.current.name', $state.current.name)
    const stateCookie = $cookies.get('stateCookie');
    $cookies.putObject('stateCookie', $state.params);
    console.log('shareUrl', shareUrl());
})
```

When changing states:

The log **'state var'** will log: `state vars tag_id=5&ticker=GOOG`

And the log **'shareUrl'** will log: `http://localhost:8080/app/#!/tag_id=5&ticker=GOOG`

---

I'm trying to just print the $location.search() results of that link first. Below I put a new log in the `$stateChangeStart` eventListener.

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$state', '$cookies', '$httpParamSerializer',
function($rootScope, $location, $state, $cookies, $httpParamSerializer) {

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
        const searchObject = $location.search();
        console.log('searchObject', searchObject);
    });
```

#### Results

I got redirected back to the login, which is expected right now. However my searchObject is still empty?

[image]

Note I also put a break point on the first line inside of the `.run`. The debugger stopped there and I tried to log out `$location.search()` while the URL was correct, but it still printed out an empty object...

[image]

When I just log out `$location` however I do see all of this:

[image]

Where to I placed that `const searchObject = $location.search();` line so I can correctly capture the pasted URL, then created new params to run a `$state.go` on to rebuild the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out!

I needed to add `?` after dashboard:

`const base = 'http://localhost:8080/app/#!/dashboard?';`

And now it will work:

[image]