# $location is not working on angular?

Tags: angularjs

i am just trying to use [angulat location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) but dont know wh it is not working =>

```
app.controller("maintainenceCtrl", function ($scope, $window, $sessionStorage, ArbreeService, $location) {
     angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            var absUrl = $location.search();
            console.log(absUrl);
        });});
```

and my url==>
http://localhost:49696/Team/Maintenance?selectionCriteria=bulkinvite

but dont know why not working ==>
 returning a null object==>console....

Comment: Try this `$location.selectionCriteria`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enable

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Then try this below way. this is the 100% correct way to get `query string` value from URL

```
 var search= $location.search();
 if(search !=null)
 {
   var objectValue = search.selectionCriteria
 }
```

### Update1

**is there any way to get just parameter values not using angular route or ui route?**

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var queryValue = getParameterByName('selectionCriteria');
```

referred from  : [Getting values from query string in an url using AngularJS $location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964444/getting-values-from-query-string-in-an-url-using-angularjs-location)

### Update 2

And you can use `$routeParams`

To get parameters from URL with `ngRoute` . It means that you will need to include [*angular-route.js*](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route) in your application as a dependency. More information how to do this on official [ngRoute documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute).

The solution for the question:

```
// You need to add 'ngRoute' as a dependency in your app
angular.module('ngApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        // configure the routing rules here
        $routeProvider.when('/backend/:type/:id', {
            controller: 'PagesCtrl'
        });

        // enable HTML5mode to disable hashbang urls
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    })
    .controller('PagesCtrl', function ($routeParams) {
        console.log($routeParams.id, $routeParams.type);
    });
```

If you don't enable the `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`. Urls will use hashbang(`/#/`).

More information about routing can be found on official angular [$route API documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route).

---

***Side note:*** This question is answering how to achieve this using ng-Route however I would recommend using the [**ui-Router**](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) for routing. It is more flexible, offers more functionality, the documentations is great and it is considered the best routing library for angular.

Comment: is there any way to get just parameter values not using angulra route  or ui route.