# angularjs $location.search returns empty object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, query-string

I want to extract my url querystring using `$location` like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964444/getting-values-from-query-string-in-an-url-using-angularjs-location).
my url - `http://someDomain.com/create/index.jsp?queryToken=123abc`

and in my directive:

```
vm.queryParam = $location.search();
$log.log('vm.queryParam', vm.queryParam); //{}
vm.details.query = vm.queryParam.queryToken;
$log.log('vm.queryToken', vm.details.query); //undefined
```

I can see the param or params when logging `$location` but what is the correct way to extract them when `search()` does not work?

Thanks.

Comment: That is just returning the url I am on.

Comment: getting any error?

Comment: No, I am a veteran in angular...

Comment: What are you getting from $location.search() ?

Comment: @slacker an empty object. It's in the question.

Comment: As I wrote, empty array.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas in your `app.config()` function have you enabled HTML5 mode? `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Comment: @George - No, why?

Comment: Try it, normally AngularJS does it's routing with `#` but with HTML5 mode it uses `/` which could explain why the `search()` isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$location.search() will work only with HTML5 mode turned on.
 Where you define your routes add this line:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

This works always:

```
$window.location.search
```

Comment: _$location.search() will work only with HTML5 mode turned on_ It works with HTML5 mode turned off as well.

Answer (score 5):

I have used this and it works, try using this

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
  })
}])
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
 $scope.myPeram = "pass some value in url ?myParam=123";
  var query = $location.search();
    if(query.myParam)
    $scope.myPeram = query.myParam;
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.20/angular.min.js"></script>

</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<span ng-bind="myPeram"></span>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```