# How Can I combine hashbang path with query parameters in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to parse a url like `http://host/file.html#/path?parameter=true` using Angular.

I thought that I could just use $location.path() and $location.search() respectively, but I'm getting an empty object from search.

This is solved by [Angularjs $location service apparently not parsing url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288190/angularjs-location-service-apparently-not-parsing-url), but if I set html5mode to true, `$location.path()` doesn't work anymore.

I don't think I need the overhead of defining routes (I will if I have to). Is this a bug in $location?

Comment: And what if you try it this way: http://host/file.html?parameter=true#/path

Comment: It works now, after I fiddled with it. I've tried the different pattern you suggest @Cherniv but that didn't work either. I'll leave the question open in case someone else has the problem and can reproduce in a plunker. If that doesn't happen I'll delete, because like this it's not so useful.

Comment: @iwein any chance you remember how you got this to work?

Comment: @caiocpricci2 I hacked it and ended up factoring out that code altogether. If you get into this mess, you're doing something else wrong I guess.