# Obtain last part of url path using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

When my app first loads I would like the obtain the last part of the url path. I use this token in order to perform requests, I am currently not using partials since its overkill for my needs. I am currently attempting to extract the path on my controller using the `$location.path()` method but it returns an empty string.

Here is my simple logging function

```
$scope.obtainTitle = function(){

        var path = $location.path();

        console.log($location);
        console.log($location.path());
        console.log($location.url());
        console.log($location.hash());

        $scope.title = decodeURIComponent(path);


    };
```

Here is the output, I am serving my site from c9 which is why I blocked out host.

[image: Console dump]

Comment: you could use `$location.url()` I think

Comment: `$location.path()` should *never* return an empty string, even if the path was the root it would still return `/`.  you should consider posting some code illustrating what's actually going on.

Comment: Check your console output for errors ? What's the url and path ?

Comment: I have added the function where I output $location and the results.

Comment: `$location.path()` is implemented as `path: locationGetterSetter('$$path', function(path) {
    path = path !== null ? path.toString() : '';
    return path.charAt(0) == '/' ? path : '/' + path;
  }),` so as @Claies said, even if path was the root it should still return `/`. So something else must be wrong in your code.

Comment: I just checked all the code and there aren't any configurations or anything is being done that could render the output as blank

Comment: what version of angular is this?  and what version of ngRoute? it is *imperative* that these two files are the same identical version.

Comment: I was using an older version (1.4.1) for angular core and 1.4.5 for ngRoute but I have now set both at 1.4.5. At the beginning of the logging function I passed a path, and it set it correctly and when called $location.path() worked as expected. So it is only the retrieval part which is not working

Comment: I just tested this error inside brackets (IDE) and I got '/' for path. So I think the error might come from the way I am serving/requesting the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs $location service apparently not parsing url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288190/angularjs-location-service-apparently-not-parsing-url)