# How to read url param in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Based on this URL, when it hits my angular controller, I need to get a value of wonum, which is "BRK18482020".

http://localhost/RealSuiteApps/RealHelp/-1/Detail?wonum=BRK18482020#/

**Is it possible?** cant understand how...

documented $location service must work, but it doesnt work :(

```
constructor(private $location: ng.ILocationService) {
   var wonum = $location.search().wonum; // DOESNT WORK, wonum undefined
   var wonum2 = $location.search()['wonum']; // DOESNT WORK, wonum undefined
```

**doesnt work**

[image]

**UPDATE**

Obviously angularJS $location doesn't work.

So, using the standard way to get the param works fine.

```
var wonum = window.location.search.split("wonum=")[1];
```

Comment: debug the code and watch the value of $location.search(), it is an object with the parameters, watch the content and tell us what you see...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063673/whats-the-most-concise-way-to-read-query-parameters-in-angularjs

Comment: user449689, how else do you think I get undefined? of course I debug it

Comment: @monstro what is the value of `$location.search()`? Does that have any data?

Comment: @monstro I understand that $location.search().wonum is undefined, but what is the value of just $location.search() ?

Answer (score 0):

See this post. [Angularjs $location service apparently not parsing url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288190/angularjs-location-service-apparently-not-parsing-url)

You are most likely missing `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in your app config. Also note, you will need a base tag in your html. `<base href="/baseUrl" />`

This also falls back to using the `#` in the url.